# Any Idea why this error occur? "Error: usePayPalScriptReducer must be used within a PayPalScriptProvider"

Tags: next.js, paypal

I'm trying to set up a PayPal Checkout...
In development env, it works but when I'm trying to deploy my code to vercel I keep getting this error:

```
Error: usePayPalScriptReducer must be used within a PayPalScriptProvider
```

Any Idea why?
Im using Server-Side-Props and Server-Side-Paths, is it related somehow?

Vercel also produce a log which stating that it might be related to https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Here is my PayPal Component:

```
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js'
import {
  getAllBootcampsSlugs,
  getBootcampDataBySlug,
} from './../../../src/utils/bootcampsApi'

function Join() {
  function createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order
      .create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              value: 5,
            },
          },
        ],
        application_context: {
          shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
        },
      })
      .then((orderID) => {
        return orderID
      })
  }

  // handles when a payment is confirmed for paypal
  async function onApprove(data, actions) {
  // Code
  }

  // handles payment errors
  function onError(data, actions) {
  // Code
  }

  return (
<div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
  <PayPalScriptProvider
    options={{
      'client-id': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
    }}>
    <PayPalButtons
      style={{
        color: 'black',
        label: 'pay',
        tagline: false,
        // layout: 'horizontal',
      }}
      createOrder={createOrder}
      onApprove={onApprove}
      onError={onError}
    />
  </PayPalScriptProvider>
</div>
  )
}

export default Join

// Return the page without additional layout.
Join.getLayout = (page) => page

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getAllBootcampsSlugs().map((bootcamp) => ({
    params: {
      bootcamp,
    },
  }))
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // Fetch Data
  const { params } = context
  const data = getBootcampDataBySlug(params.bootcamp)
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  }
}
```

Many Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: You reference code that does not exist in your question. Where is usePayPalScriptReducer being used.

Comment: It not. I never added that and that exactly what is so wierd

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `usePayPalScriptReducer` from within a `PayPalScriptProvider` component like so:

```
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalButtons,
    usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const ButtonWrapper = () => {
    // usePayPalScriptReducer can be use only inside children of PayPalScriptProviders
    // This is the main reason to wrap the PayPalButtons in a new component
    const [{ options, isPending }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    return (
        <PayPalButtons ... />
    )
}

const ProviderWrapper = () => {
    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider ...>
            <ButtonWrapper />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    )
}

export default ProviderWrapper;
```

For more information, please checkout the documentation: https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nextJs 13, what you'll do is to wrap the entire layout.js with a PayPalScript Provider from a client directive

In the app directory, create a file called "PaypalProvider.js" with the following code snippet ----------------->

```js
'use client'

import { PayPalScriptProvider } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";


export const PayPalProvider = ({children}) => {
    return <PayPalScriptProvider>{children}</PayPalScriptProvider>
}
```

Then in your layout.js wrap the paypal provider with other provider, if any, just like this --------------->

```js
import { StoreProvider } from '../store/provider';
import '../styles/globals.scss';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { NextAuthProvider } from './Providers';
import { PayPalProvider } from './PayPalProvider';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: '',
  description: '',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <PayPalProvider>
        <NextAuthProvider>
        <StoreProvider>
        {children}
        </StoreProvider>
        </NextAuthProvider>
        </PayPalProvider>
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

That's all, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root file of your project which I am guessing would be _app.js in the pages folder and wrap your entire component with PayPalScriptProvider like this:

```
import { PayPalScriptProvider } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import "@/styles/globals.scss";

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <>
       <PayPalScriptProvider deferLoading={true}>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
       </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```